# How do I get Access Keys?

Tags: everspace

I found a Secure Container. It says I need Access Keys to open it. And, sadly, Everspace's standard container-access method didn't work (i.e., I shot it, and it didn't open).

Where do I find Access Keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access keys can occasionally spawn in stacks of two as Bonus Equipment (as a Perk) before a run, or they can be purchased from Traders and Service Traders.

Access keys can spawn after defeating Elite enemies (the drop rate is 75% as of the latest update).

According to [this forum post by Giraffasaur](https://forum.everspace-game.com/discussion/4298/access-keys-and-mainframe-overrides), if you use Mainframe Override on an Elite, “you can take them down without any form of retaliation.”